# How to split a java string with "("?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a java string with the character "(".

For example :

> split("wer(sde")= "wer"+"sde".

But it give exception. Is there a way to split this string using split() function without changing the character "(" to some other character.

```
String[] cp=cmd.split("{");
```

Output:
**Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition**

Comment: escape it with \\ Characters/expressions that have a specific meaning in regex have to be escaped to be interpreted as character.

Comment: split( "\\\(" );

Comment: @Basi compile error, `\(` is not a valid Java character, needs a second escape `\\(`

Comment: or `split("[()]")` since you want to split at `(` or `)` - inside `[]` they lose the special meaning

Answer (score 4):

The thing is, [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) receives as parameter a *regular expression*. Both `{}` and `()` are meta-characters and have a special meaning in a regex, so you need to escape them like this:

```
String[] cp = cmd.split("\\(|\\)");
```

Answer (score 3):

The method [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) of `String` accept a `String`, that parameter is a regex :

> ```
> public String[] split(String regex)
> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
> ```

Since `(` is a reserved character in regex, you need to escape it `\(`.
But in Java, you need to escape twice `\\(`, once for the `String` and the second for the regex

This gives :

```
s.split("\\(");
```

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses mean something in RegEx, they're used to group characters together. As such, if you intend to reference the literal character, `'('` you must escape it within the RegEx:

```
String[] cp = cmd.split("\\(");
```

Note the use of two backslashes. This is because the JVM will also interpret a backslash as a metacharacter for escape purposes, so you must **escape** the backslash itself with another backslash in order for it to make it into the RegEx.